# box-shadow inset no longer working in Edge?

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

Why would this no longer be working in Microsoft Edge?:

```
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 350px #000 inset;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0px 0px 350px #000 inset;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 350px #000 inset;
```

Here's an example (the hero graphic should have an inset box shadow - which it does in Firefox and Chrome):
[www.gallowaycottageholidays.com](http://www.gallowaycottageholidays.com)

Thank you.
NJ

Comment: Microsoft edge has the same rendering engine as edge, so if it works in Chrome it works also in Edge. Unless you need to support any old version? In this case please specify what version (and why) you need to still support it?

Comment: It's working for me in the current Edge 85.

Comment: I am not sure which 'hero graphic' you are talking about? Please try to provide detailed information about it. If possible then try to provide a small sample code here, it can help us to reproduce the issue instead of checking your whole site. Let us know, whether you are using the MS Edge legacy browser or using the MS Edge Chromium browser? I try to test your sample CSS code and it shows similar results in MS Edge legacy, MS Edge Chromium browser, and Google Chrome browser.

Comment: Microsoft Edge Version 86.0.622.63 (Official build) (64-bit) isn't rendering the box-shadow, which should be appearing bottom and right of every hero graphic on the page detailed above.  It's also happening on this site www.aaronhjones.com.  Firefox and Chrome are rendering fine.

Comment: In Edge, we had to reduce the blur value for each screen resolution.  You can't, for example, have a 250px blur on a 1920 x whatever res, nor can you have a 350px blur on a 1366 x whatever res.  There was definitely an issue, and we resolved it thanks to Edge's 'Inspect' option.  Thank you.